# Why In a Bean Class Some Instance Make Cloneable

Tags: java

Is there are necessary to some instance of bean class getter and setter method to be clone able implement

```
public class RelyingPartyNotaryDoc implements Serializable {
 @Column(name = "doc_content")
    private byte[] docBytes;

public byte[] getDocBytes() {
        if (docBytes == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return docBytes.clone();
    }

    public void setDocBytes(byte[] bytes) {
        if (bytes == null) {
            docBytes = null;
        } else {
            docBytes = bytes.clone();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a good idea to clone arrays in getters and setters because nothing prevents the caller to change the elements of the array.

Answer (score 1):

There are two *cloning* aspects in your question.

**First** is the `Serializable` interface. Since this is a hibernate Entity from what I see (or any other ORM Entity), this is not a must requirement. But could be if you are using detached entities for example. So the answer here is .. it depends.

The **second** clone part is your two methods: `getDocBytes` and `setDocBytes`that *use the clone* method to create a copy of an array. If you would not clone the incoming array - you could modify it's content. Cloning the array prevents this modification.

Comment: can you elaborate this because Serializable  just insure that class is Serializable  but where is effected in jdk

Comment: @JDevil the *Serializable* interface is required by some frameworks under some conditions, for example Hibernate requires this for detached entities.